# Finding a static pointer to a object?

Tags: c++, plugins, reverse-engineering

Hey I'm implementing a plugin system for my application (but for them to be able to draw etc they need my Window classes and all of that)

Like this:

```
CWindow* window = new CWindow();
```

This is done on startup, obviously if I did this:

```
std::cout << window << std::endl;
```

the pointer would change every time the application is ran again.

How can I find a static pointer for it (that doesn't change) so that I can have in my plugin SDK like:

```
CWindow* GetWindow() {
  return (CWindow*)Addres;
}
```

Comment: make object itself static... everything allocated by new will have dynamic address. (for example: `static CWindow window; return &window;`)

Comment: But don't you have a new window every time you start the application? Why would you be surprised that the pointer returned would be different every time? Also, if it would even be possible to use a single fixed address for the window, how would you be able to run multiple instances of your program? Instead the solution is very simple: Pass the window the the plugins initialization function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg oh yea ofcourse that'd work! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need this address to be the same on every run of the program: you just need to know where you can reliably find this address.

As a quick and dirty solution (example), you could store the address returned by `new CWindow()`in a global variable declared in a header **that you will include in you plugin**: the variable would then be accessible to your plugin, giving the plugin access to the window's address. The actual value of this address is just an accident.

Comment: I just pass it in the Init function instead.. :P

Comment: So you do not have a question ; )

Comment: No Joachim gave a good tip, which I considered much easier ^_^